# Python pandas read .txt files and export .csv with separating colums

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

i have a problem, i tried to read a .txt file and exported to .csv and separating the lines using a delimiter by colums using categories.

**file.txt**  is like this

```
[groups] 
admins = user1,user2,user3 
users_network = user4,user5 
users_m4s = user6,user7,user8,user9
```

and the **.csv** file should be

```
groups

user1 = admins
user2 = admins
user3 = admins
user4 = users_network
user5 = users_network
user6 = users_m4s ... for the rest of element of category line
```

i tried

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_table("D:\GIT-files\Automate-Stats\SVN_sample_files\sample_svn_input.txt" , sep='\=',engine='python')
print(df)

df.to_csv("D:\GIT-files\Automate-Stats\SVN_sample_files\sample_svn_input_update.csv" , index=None)

df = pd.read_table ("D:\GIT-files\Automate-Stats\SVN_sample_files\sample_svn_input_update.csv" , sep='\=',engine='python')
print(df)
```

but its not creating right the .csv and display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the results you needed based on the provided code with this line of code

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\GIT-files\Automate-Stats\SVN_sample_files\sample_svn_input.txt", sep = '|')
df.columns = ['groups']
df['New Columns'] = df['groups'].apply(lambda x : x.split('=')[0])
df['groups'] = df['groups'].apply(lambda x : ' '.join(x.split('=')[1:]))
df['groups'] = df['groups'].apply(lambda x : x.split(','))
df = df.explode('groups')
df['groups'] = df['New Columns'] + ' = ' + df['groups']
df = df[['groups']]
df.to_csv("D:\GIT-files\Automate-Stats\SVN_sample_files\sample_svn_input_update.csv" , index = False)
```

Comment: i have this error KeyError                                  `Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()



KeyError: 'New Columns' `

Comment: df['groups'] = df['New Columns'] + ' = ' + df['groups'] here is the error @ArchAngelPwn, about keyError on New column

Comment: If you take out the last 3 rows of code (everything after the explode) and look at the df does it give you expected results that are just in 2 separate columns (without the = sign in them)?

Comment: yes and in py charm its working, do you have also discord to send you a screen shot? @ArchAngelPwn